# Assembly X86 language questions

Tags: assembly, x86

Print the message one character at a time in reverse
order. Name the program HELLO4.ASM. (Use “push” and
“pop”

Reserve another variable which will hold the message in
reverse order using “push” and “pop” functions.Then print this message using either
function 9 or function 40h. Name this program HELLO5.ASM.

This is my assignment about the assembly language, and this is i working so far.But it's doesn't reverse.

```
    ; (Hello4)

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

.data
aName BYTE "Hello, DOS Here!$"
nameSize = ($ - aName) - 1

.code
main PROC
    mov ecx,nameSize
    esi,0
L1: movzx eax,aName[esi]
    push eax
    inc esi 
    loop L1

    mov ecx,nameSize
    esi,0
L2: pop eax
    mov aName[esi],al
    inc esi
    loop L2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h


main ENDP
end main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fixing some oops in your code and intializing data segment manually :

```
 ; (Hello4)

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

.data
aName BYTE "Hello, DOS Here!$"
nameSize = ($ - aName) - 1

.code
main PROC
    mov ax,@data          ;◄■■ INITIALIZE DATA
    mov ds,ax             ;◄■■ SEGMENT MANUALLY.
    mov ecx,nameSize
    esi,0                 ;◄■■ MOV ESI,0
L1: movzx eax,aName[esi]
    push eax
    inc esi 
    loop L1

    mov ecx,nameSize
    esi,0                 ;◄■■ MOV ESI,0
L2: pop eax
    mov aName[esi],al
    inc esi
    loop L2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h


main ENDP
end main
```

After previous changes it worked for me and displayed the string backwards.